# How to use Android webview to run javascript that depends on another library/module

Tags: javascript, android, webview

We can run simple javascript function (jsCode) like:

```
function() {
   return "test"
}
```

in webview:

```
String js = "(" + jsCode + ") ();"
mWebView.evaluateJavascript(js, new ValueCallback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
        Log.d("return value: ", s); // Returns the value from the function
    }
});
```

But what if my javascript depends on another module or reference another file like:

```
import { double } from 'mymodule';
```

Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this by evaluating the external javascript file before evaluating the jsCode

```
private String[] jsFiles = {"external_lib.js", "main.js"};

private void evaluateJS() {
        try {
            String js = readFromAssets(jsFiles[fileIndex]);
            Log.e(TAG, "evaluating: " + jsFiles[fileIndex]);
            mWebView.evaluateJavascript(js, new ValueCallback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
                    fileIndex++;
                    if (fileIndex == jsFiles.length) {
                        // we have evaluated the last javascript file
                        Log.e("return value: ", s); // Returns the value from the function
                        return;
                    }
                    evaluateJS();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        }
    }
```

the code in main.js uses variables and functions that are defined in external_lib.js